# How to turn sql rows into columns?

Tags: sql, wordpress, mariadb, pivot, pivot-table

I have some problems with transpose row to columns.

Site based on Wordpress
DataBase: MariaDB
Pivot functionality: off (i guess)

I have a sql table in this format:

```
FIELD_NAME  FIELD_VALUE
your-name   Nazar
location    Ukraine
your-email  uubukraine@gmail.com
telephone   0992312167
your-browser    OPERA
```

Can you tell me how to turn her into this?

```
Your-Name  Location Your-Email    telephone   your-browser
Nazar      Ukraine  u@gmail.com   0992312167     opera
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work correctly.

```
SELECT
    submit_time,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-name',     field_value, NULL)) AS Requestor,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-email',    field_value, NULL)) AS Email,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'location',      field_value, NULL)) AS Company_Name,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'telephone',      field_value, NULL)) AS Telephone,
FROM
    wpv4_contactic_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product  (and there is no `IF` in "SQL"). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have a `submit_time`, so the query doesn't match your sample data.  Also, explain what you mean by "it doesn't work correctly".

Comment: @openshac . . . `PIVOT` is NOT a SQL keyword.  `PIVOT` is bespoke (i.e. not standard) functionality supported by a handful of databases, primarily SQL Server.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  That's why there's a problem. I can't use PIVOT to sort out

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Site based on Wordpress
DataBase: MariaDB
Pivot functionality: off (i guess)

Comment: @openshac I can't use PIVOT to sort.

Comment: Follow the `[pivot-table]` tag for many suggestions on code.

Comment: For Pivoting in MariaDB, see See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831